# Report screenshot attachment link is confused

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I've embedding several screenshots of various states of UI. The screenshots are attached however, the link to view the attachments are confused and opening another attachment on the report.

For e.g. 'Attachment 1 (PNG)' link to a screenshot opens/collapses the 2nd screenshot and the same with others.

I'm wondering if there is an option to customize a link text, instead of saying "Attachment 1 (PNG)" to something like "Current User Data Screenshot", to be more interactive.

I tried to upgrade the cucumber-JVM version but the issue is still there.

Comment: Screenshots are not attached. Can you edit the question and reattach?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the screenshot file and then attach to the scenario.

```
 //take screenshot using selenium
    File src = driv.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    //Rename the file
      File newfile =new File("Current User Data Screenshot"); // Need absolute file name
     if(src.renameTo(newfile)){
                System.out.println("File renamed");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Sorry! the file can't be renamed");
            }


    //convert the screenshot to byte array

    BufferedImage o=ImageIO.read(newfile);
    ByteArrayOutputStream b=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(o, "png", b);
    byte[] myscreenshot=b.toByteArray()

//Attach the screenshot to scenario 
scenario.embed(myscreenshot,"image/png");
```

Comment: I'm getting still the same issue.
`public void embedScreenshotToReport(Scenario scenario) {
  scenario.embed(((TakesScreenshot) getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES), "image/png");
 }`